# Deploy Spring-boot application to Weblogic : getting error

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic

I'm trying to deploy a spring-boot application in a weblogic server.
Therefore I follow some documented instructions such as:

```
 - create webapp folder

 - create  dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml

 - create weblogic.xml
 - make MyApplication class extends
        SpringBootServletInitializer and implements WebApplicationInitializer, 
 - turn the scope of embedded server to provided

{

    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
    }

 - packaging to WAR in pom.xml

Unfortunetely, I'm getting:

<blockquote>
May 30, 2018 11:51:54 AM BST Warning Deployer BEA-149078 Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
null
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.createModuleException(WebAppModule.java:1824)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:270)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.init(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

</blockquote>
```

I've tried some things, but I couldn't figure out why the deployment is null?

Any clue?

Thanks
    Rui

Comment: The version of WebLogic that you are using contains a version of ASM that cannot read the byte code produced by the version of Java that you are using. You either need to upgrade WebLogic or to compile your application with a lower target so that it produces byte code that WebLogic can cope with. I can't be more specific than that as you haven't provided any information about the versions of the various things that you're using.

Comment: Hi. It was exactly that.
I'm really a newbie and I couldn't identify the cause from the stacktrace.

Weblogic running with java 7, and the war generated with java 8.
Thank you very much.

Comment: If you target a lower Java version won't it break Spring? From what I understood the latest versions of Spring Boot only run on Java 8 or higher.